# Threading with glut: glutPostRedisplay being ignored

Tags: opengl, glut, freeglut

I have a program which updates it the program output then the state of the program changes. This happens when a ticker of the time (not an openGL timer, one implemented in threads) happens, and when keyboard input is registered from glut (using glutKeyboardFunc callback).

Both of these events update the programs state and call glutPostRedisplay; the problem is only the when the keyboard is pressed does it actually do anything. When the timer ticks the display function is ignored, but when the keyboard is pressed the display function is called.

Does glut ignore other threads? And if so is there a way to get it to register them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot call `glutPostRedisplay` or most other GLUT functions from a thread other than the one GLUT was initialized in. GLUT is *not* thread-safe.

Comment: @111111: Or you could just use a thread-safe signaling system to let the GLUT thread know that it needed to render.

Comment: I have it to work if i added a blank glut idel func, this way it checks whether glutpostredisplay has called, however it saturates the CPU, do you have a better idea as to how to notify glut with out a polling checking loop.

Comment: @111111: In the idle func try to get hold of a semaphore with some timeout. If the semaphore can be aquired cosider this the signal and call glutPostRedisplay, if it runs into a timeout exit the idle function so that events get processes. Not that this use of multithreading will give in fact decrease performance. The idea of multithreading is to keep all CPUs busy with usefull stuff.

Comment: @datenwolf, In the end I realised I wasn't far enough into my project to ditch glut and go with glfw, with which you manage your own master loop. In which I have implemented something very similar to what you have recommended via std::condition_varaible::wait_for